# Populate DropDownList row source from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have been trying to bind an attribute from an xml file to a dropdownlist containing unique values.  The attribute is the 'yearno' in the 'season' tag.  The sample xml file contains single values of a season only, but multiple values do occur.  However, the row source data should contain each season only once.
So far I have had no luck getting the seasons to show in the dropdownlist.  I have tried several different options in the XPath of the XmlDataSource, to no avail.

Can anybody help me please?

Below is part of the page code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="Activiteiten" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Activities_past_CPY.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoadLectureList.Activities" />

 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">


  <p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Seasonlist" runat="server" Width="130" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource2" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
  </p>

    <p>
    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/Lectures.xml" 
        XPath="//lectures/season[@yearno]/lecture" />

  </p>

  </asp:Content>
```

Here is the XML file:

> 

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lectures>
  <season yearno="2012">
    <lecture>
      <date>26 september 2011</date>
      <speaker>Dhr. Sylvain Ephimenco</speaker>
      <speakerdsc>
          Experience of the speaker.
      </speakerdsc>
      <subject>De Arabische volksopstanden</subject>
      <subjectdsc>
          Interesting subject
      </subjectdsc>
      <speakerpic>sylvain-ephimenco.jpg</speakerpic>
      <subjectpic1></subjectpic1>
      <subjectpic2></subjectpic2>
    </lecture>
  </season>
  <season yearno="2013">
    <lecture>
      <date>14 januari 2013</date>
      <speaker>Mr. Wim A. Egger</speaker>
      <speakerdsc>
        More experience of this speaker.
      </speakerdsc>
      <subject>Surinaamse rug, Joodse buik</subject>
      <subjectdsc>
        Another interesting subject
      </subjectdsc>
      <speakerpic>wim egger.jpg</speakerpic>
      <subjectpic1>rug_buik.jpg</subjectpic1>
      <subjectpic2></subjectpic2>
    </lecture>
  </season>
  <season yearno="2014">
    <lecture>
      <date>10 maart 2014</date>
      <speaker>Drs. C. Weltevrede</speaker>
      <speakerdsc>
        This man's curriculum.
      </speakerdsc>
      <subject>De joodse gemeente van Dordrecht tussen 1933 en heden</subject>
      <subjectdsc>
        Gotta hear this lecture
      </subjectdsc>
      <speakerpic>cees_weltevrede.jpg</speakerpic>
      <subjectpic1>synagoge_dordrecht.jpg</subjectpic1>
      <subjectpic2>tallit.tif</subjectpic2>
    </lecture>
  </season>
  <season yearno="2014">
    <lecture>
          <datum>28 april 2014</datum>
      <speaker>Prof. dr. P. W. van der Horst </speaker>
      <speakerdsc>
        Life course of this speaker.
      </speakerdsc>
      <subject>Joodse cultuur tussen Bijbel en Misjna</subject>
      <subjectdsc>
        Don't miss this one
      </subjectdsc>
      <speakerpic></speakerpic>
      <subjectpic1>talmoed.jpg</subjectpic1>
      <subjectpic2></subjectpic2>
    </lecture>
  </season>
</lectures>
`
```

I have searched and found many approaches on forums, but have had none to accomplish my aim.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess your xpath should be `/lectures/season/@yearno`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is reading your xml file by dataset. After that you can bind the datatable to a Dropdown List whithout any problem.